# Puppteer.js return timeout after from submit

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm submitting my form but after post submit it return  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 10000 ms exceeded`  below is the snippet of similar code.

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/admin');

  await page.type('#username', 'foo@example.com');
  await page.type('#password', 'password');
  await page.click('#btnsubmit');

  await page.waitForNavigation();
  console.log('New Page URL:', page.url());
```

have checked a lot but not able to find how to debug.
getting below error

```
(node:16764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 10002 ms exceeded
    at E:\wamp\www\pupserver\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111
    at async FrameManager.waitForFrameNavigation (E:\wamp\www\pupserver\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:127:23)
    at async Frame.waitForNavigation (E:\wamp\www\pupserver\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\FrameManager.js:441:16)
    at async Page.waitForNavigation (E:\wamp\www\pupserver\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:794:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Socket.<anonymous> (E:\wamp\www\pupserver\app.js:192:3)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16764) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be some race conditions with the click and waiting for navigation. Usual asvice is to try this:

```js
await Promise.all([
  page.click('#btnsubmit'),
  page.waitForNavigation(),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/admin', {
        waitUntil: 'load',
        // Remove the timeout
        timeout: 0
    });

  await page.type('#username', 'foo@example.com');
  await page.type('#password', 'password');

  await page.click('#btnsubmit').then(() => page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'}));
  console.log('New Page URL:', page.url());
```

Comment: it goes to "https://www.google.com/admin", but hangs after `button submit`

Comment: I don't see any button in `google.com/admin` page

Comment: It's just a reference.. i have button in the actual form...

Comment: Try again please